# How can I force order of execution of instructions in Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have noticed, that Scala doesn't always execute instructions in order. For example, if you have the following instructions.

```
var a = command1.!
var b = command2.!
```

The second instruction may be executed before the first one because it doesn't have any dependency on that instruction. So, my question is, how can I force the second instruction to be executed after the first instruction.

Comment: Could you please provide  a real example?

Comment: Basically, In the first part of my code, I am writing something to a file. And then later on that file is read. I want to make sure the file is not read before its written. I would have no problem if I was using file write/read libraries, but I am writing and reading those files using the processbuilder. So, the scala code isn't really aware of that, and maybe will try to execute them out of order to improve performance.

Comment: ... Then you need to synchronize it somehow, like with `!` (blocks until the external command exits), use another that takes the output of the first and have them run sequentially, etc. http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question, How do I compose ProcessBuilder?, the doc says:

> Two existing ProcessBuilder can be combined in the following ways:
>
> They can be executed in parallel, with the output of the first being
>   fed as input to the second, like Unix pipes. This is achieved with the #| method.
>
> They can be executed in sequence, with the second starting as soon as
>   the first ends. This is done by the ### method.
>
> The execution of the second one can be conditioned by the return code
>   (exit status) of the first, either only when it's zero, or only when
>   it's not zero. The methods #&& and #|| accomplish these tasks.